# Density and partial pressure

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium, pressure, density

A sample of $\ce{NOBr}$ gas was placed in a rigid flask where it decomposes at $\pu{25 ^\circ C}$ according to the following reaction:

$$\ce{2NOBr(g) <=> 2NO(g) + Br2(g)}$$

At equilibrium, the total pressure and density of the gas mixture are $\pu{0.0515 atm}$ and $\pu{0.1861 g/l}$, respectively. I'm trying to find the partial fractions of each component using $pv=nRT$, but I'm a little confused. I cannot find an expression that allows me to relate the density that was given.

Comment: You can get the average molar mass of ideal gas from the pressure and density. From that, you can get partial fractions.

Comment: Do you mean partial pressure ??

Comment: yes, I wrote it wrong. Can you help me?

Comment: @WagnerCoelho You can answer this question did you saw the crucial point the question says its a  **rigid flask** meaning the volume of the system dose not change also the mass of the total system stays constant in chemical reactions thus the density of the system is constant (initial and final stats) use that *hint* and try to solve this problem.